# AVL Tree unit test, get the height of nodes without parents

Tags: c, unit-testing, binary-search-tree

For my school assignment I have to implement an AVL tree node insertion. I have this unit test, with 4 tests, and 2 of them always fails.
I use two global variables, one Array to store the numbers and one integer for the index.

```
int pom = 0;
int test_output[1000];
```

The first 2 test checks the rotations with parents:

```
void test_right_rotation_with_parent() {
    //Arrange
    struct Node* root = NULL;
    int insert_nodes[] = { 15,10,5 };
    int correct_output[] = { 10,2,5,1,15,1 }; // node -> key, node -> height;
    char* passed = PASSED;

    //Act
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        insert(root, insert_nodes[i]);
    }

    preOrder(root);

    //Assert
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (correct_output[i] != test_output[i]) {
            passed = FAILED;
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("%s: %s\n", __func__, passed);

}
```

Output: test_right_rotation_with_parent: PASSED.

Same test for left rotation. Then I have 2 test for rotations without parents. These are the test which I cannot pass.

```
void test_right_rotation_without_parent() {
    //Arrange
    struct Node* root = NULL;
    int insert_nodes[] = { 20,25,15,10,5 };
    int correct_output[] = { 20,3,10,2,5,1,15,1,25,1 }; // node -> key, node -> height;
    char* passed = PASSED;

    //Act
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        insert(root, insert_nodes[i]);
    }

    preOrder(root);

    ...
}
```

Output: test_right_rotation_without_parent: FAILED

PreOrder:

```
void preOrder(struct Node *root) {
    if (root != NULL) { // this is the main problem if a node hasn't got parent
        test_output[pom++] = root->key;
        test_output[pom++] = root->height;
        preOrder(root->link[0]); // left side
        preOrder(root->link[1]); // right side
    }
}
```

And this is the part of the insert function, which creates a Node, if previously there wasn't any.

```
struct Node *insert(struct Node *node, int key)
{
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        struct Node *node = malloc(sizeof *node);
        if (node != NULL) 
        {

        /* if I do the same thing here which I did in preOrder,
         * the sequence of the keys will be correct,
         * however the height will always be 1 (for the without parent functions) */

            node->key = key;
            node->height = 1;
            node->link[0] = node->link[1] = NULL;
        }

        return node;
    }
    else {...}
```

Is it possible to make this work with this method? Or I need to find another method if I want to pass these test?